# What does the direction of the arrow mean on DVI to VGA adapters?

Tags: graphics-card, vga, dvi, adapter

I was replacing a monitor today and I noticed that the DVI to VGA adapter had an arrow on it that would either point left or right (provided you have it oriented like a pyramid with the side with the arrow facing up).

There were both left and right arrow facing adapters in the box, and the one that worked I attached on the video card had a left arrow on it.

Does this mean that the one with the right arrow works when it connects to the monitor?

[image: dvi to VGA adapter with arrow]

Comment: An image would be helpful

Comment: If it [looks like a TV screen with a square wave, with an arrowhead on the end](http://cdn.overclock.net/7/70/70c769a7_DL-DVI.jpeg), I'm pretty sure that just means it's a DVI port, but I can't find any source reference to confirm that.  As Moab said, a picture would help us confirm what it is you're talking about exactly. :)  Having said that, I'm quite positive there no such thing as a 'cable-end-specific' DVI->VGA adaptor, and I'd guess the two adapters you have function identically.

Comment: It looks like an indicator for digital side here.

Comment: @Hennes well it would be nice if it actually pointed at something other than the wall or the person next to me.

Comment: it is a sensely logo though. That adapter takes the **analog** signal from a DVI plug and reroutes the wires to a VGA plug. It does nothing with a digital signal.

Comment: The direction of the arrow means nothing AFAIK. For example, two of the adapters I have in my hand have the symbol on both sides, and if I flip it, the arrow is still pointing in the same direction.  So one side is pointing to the analog pins, and the arrow on the opposite side is pointing to the digital pins.  Also, on this DVI-D video card in front of me here, the symbol is also there and it's pointing to the right, when the port itself actually runs vertically.  So it's not pointing at any set of pins, and it has nothing to do with analog capabilities (since it's a DVI-D connector).

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I dunno, I've had varied results with these things, and it seems that it had to do with the direction of the arrow.  So either all the ones I have with the arrow facing the other way are bad, or that arrow actually means something...

Comment: How do you know it's going the "other way", and not just stamped in an upside down orientation?  Does it have the same logo on the reverse side? If so, does it point to the same edge of the adapter as the other?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 no it is only on one side on all of them.

Comment: Yeah, some of them are stamped on one side, other on both, depends on the manufacturer it seems.  Anyhow as I said, I have a few here, and have dealt with dozens an dozens of them over the years, and they are all electrically the same -- there is no end-specific, or unidirectional versions of the adapters.  Since there isn't, the direction of the arrow does not mean what you're suggesting, and from what I can tell and have experiences, it's just a logo, the direction of the arrow means nothing...

Answer (score -1):

I believe it indicates which type of converter it is. For example, DVI to VGA or VGA to DVI, but honestly I don't know which direction defines which source it can take